# How can i avoid a lot of if statements?

Tags: python

I want to have a program where i can write things in a variable for example "delete file" and it deletes the specific file. To check what is in this variable i have for every command an if statement if the variable is "delte file" or "open file" etc etc. How can i avoid all of the if statements?

if you need it heres my code:

```
import time
import os


comreal = 0
com = input("Command: ")

if com == "open file" or com == "openfile":
  comreal = comreal + 1
  file = input("File Name: ")
  os.system(file)


if com == "delete file" or com == "deletefile":
   comreal = comreal + 1
   filefordelete = input("File name: ")
   if os.path.exists(filefordelete):
       suretodelete = input("Are you sure? Y/N ")
       if suretodelete == "Y" or suretodelete == "y":
         os.remove(filefordelete)
         print("Deleting successful")
       elif suretodelete == "N" or suretodelete == "n":
           print("Deleting stopped!")
   else:
      print("File does not exist!")
   

if com == "create file" or com == "createfile":
    comreal = comreal + 1
    filename = input("Name of the file you want to create: ")
    filename2 = str(filename) + ".txt"
    textinput = input("Text: ")
    with open(filename2, "w") as a:
        a.write(textinput)


if comreal == 0:
    print("This command does not exist")



input("Press enter to exit ")
```

i tried it with one if statements and the rest just elif but that didnt work.

Comment: Put each operation in a function. Then use a dictionary that maps from command names to functions.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python 3.10 or higher, you can use the match statement in these situations:

```py
com = input("Command: ")

match com:
    case "open file" | "openfile":
        # open file task.
        print('open file.')

    case "delete file" | "deletefile":
        # delete file task.
        print('delete file.')

    case "create file" | "createfile":
        # create file task.
        print('create file.')

    case _:
        # Any case other than the cases above.
        print('unknown command.')
```

Also, another practical way is to write functions both for more readability and for use in dictionaries.

```py
com = input("Command: ")


def open_file():
    # open file task.
    print('open file.')

def delete_file():
    # delete file task.
    print('delete file.')

def create_file():
    # create file task.
    print('create file.')


def default():
    # Any case other than the cases above.
    print('unknown command.')


commands = {
    'open file': open_file,
    'delete file': delete_file,
    'create file': create_file
}


func = commands.get(com, default)

# run the command:
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than taking arbitrary input, you could create a proper command-line tool.

With a class to group your functions:

```py
import os
import argparse
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Commands:
    file_name: str  
    text: str

    def open_file(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.file_name):
            # Windows
            if sys.platform == "win32":
                os.startfile(outfile)
            # Mac
            elif "mac" in sys.platform or "darwin" in sys.platform:
                os.system(f'open "{self.file_name}"')
            # Linux
            elif "posix" in sys.platform or "linux" in sys.platform:
                os.system(f'xdg-open "{self.file_name}"')
            print(f"{self.file_name} opened!")
        else:
            print(f"{self.file_name} does not exist!")

    def delete_file(self):
        try:
            os.remove(self.file_name)
            print(f"Successfully deleted {self.file_name}")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"{self.file_name} does not exist!")

    def create_file(self):
        if not self.file_name.endswith(".txt"):
            self.file_name += ".txt"
        with open(self.file_name, "w") as f:
            f.write(self.text)
        print(f"{self.file_name} created!")
```

An Argument Parser:

```py
def default_args(subparser):
    subparser.add_argument("file_name", help="File Name")


def get_args() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("File Processor")
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="Choose a command!", dest="command")

    open_file = subparsers.add_parser("open", help="Open a file")
    delete_file = subparsers.add_parser("delete", help="Delete a file")
    create_file = subparsers.add_parser("create", help="Create a file")
    for subparser in (open_file, delete_file, create_file):
        default_args(subparser)

    create_file.add_argument("--text", help="What text should the file contain?", default="")
    parser.set_defaults(text="")
    return parser.parse_args()
```

And the main program:

```py
def main():
    args = get_args()
    cmds = Commands(args.file_name, args.text)
    match args.command:
        case "open":
            cmds.open_file()
        case "delete":
            cmds.delete_file()
        case "create": 
            cmds.create_file()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Test it by running:

```bash
python <your_script_here>.py create "text.txt" --text "Hello World"
python <your_script_here>.py open "text.txt"
python <your_script_here>.py delete "text.txt"
```

Take a look at the help by running any of:

```bash
python <your_script_here>.py --help

python <your_script_here>.py open --help

python <your_script_here>.py delete --help

python <your_script_here>.py create --help
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an object-oriented approach. First create a Command enum with each profile having a implementation for an abstract `execute` operation:

```
import os
from enum import Enum
class Command(Enum):
    OPEN_FILE = ("open file", "open_file")
    DELETE_FILE = ("delete file", "deletefile")
    CREATE_FILE = ("create file", "createfile")

    def __init__(self, command, command_alias):
        self.command = command
        self.command_alias = command_alias

    @staticmethod
    def validate_if_file_exists(filename):
     if os.path.exists(filename):
      return
     raise FileNotFoundError("File " + filename + " not found!")

    def execute(self, filename):
        command_mapping = {
            self.OPEN_FILE:  self._execute_open,
            self.DELETE_FILE: self._execute_delete,
            self.CREATE_FILE: self._execute_create,
        }
        command_mapping[self](filename)

    @staticmethod
    def _execute_open(filename):
        Command.validate_if_file_exists(filename)
        os.system(filename)

    @staticmethod
    def _execute_delete(filename):
        Command.validate_if_file_exists(filename)
        sure_to_delete = input("Are you sure? Y/N ")
        if sure_to_delete.lower() == "y":
            os.remove(filename)
            print("Deleting successful")
        elif sure_to_delete.lower() == "n":
            print("Deleting stopped!")

    @staticmethod
    def _execute_create(filename):
        filename2 = str(filename) + ".txt"
        text_input = input("Text: ")
        with open(filename2, "w") as file:
            file.write(text_input)

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, value):
        for member in cls:
            if member.command == value or member.command_alias == value:
                return member
        raise KeyError(f"No enum member with value '{value}'")
```

Then your main code can look like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    comreal = 0
    com = input("Command: ")
    try:
        command = Command.get(com)
        comreal += 1
        filename = input("Enter the file name.")
        command.execute(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Operation failed due to the following error: ")
        traceback.print_exc()
```

So all the execution logic will remain in the `Command` class, and you can just execute the abstract implementation in the main code.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are already quite good. They change the structure of your code and introduce new concepts, that help you to decompose the algorithm.

Without changing too much of your code, in case you prefer a pure imperative approach (Your code looks like you do.), I recommend the following options to consider.

1. Try to have the normal control flow as linear as possible. The standard case should not be nested within three levels of if-clauses.
2. Try to define very local functions.
3. Use rejecting branches that return. ("Fail Fast" approach)
4. Keep things, that belong to each other together.

I only illustrate this on a few lines of your example.

Instead of the following

```
if com == "delete file" or com == "deletefile":
   comreal = comreal + 1
   filefordelete = input("File name: ")
   if os.path.exists(filefordelete):
       suretodelete = input("Are you sure? Y/N ")
       if suretodelete == "Y" or suretodelete == "y":
         os.remove(filefordelete)
         print("Deleting successful")
       elif suretodelete == "N" or suretodelete == "n":
           print("Deleting stopped!")
   else:
      print("File does not exist!")
```

you can write

```
if com == "delete file" or com == "deletefile":
   def deletete_file():
     comreal = comreal + 1
     filefordelete = input("File name: ")
     if not(os.path.exists(filefordelete)):
        return print("File does not exist!")
     suretodelete = input("Are you sure? Y/N ")
     if suretodelete == "N" or suretodelete == "n":
        return print("Deleting stopped!")
     if suretodelete != "Y" and suretodelete != "y":
        return
     os.remove(filefordelete)
     print("Deleting successful")
  deletete_file()
```

Many developers recommend you not to write code in such a way, because returning early is often seen as bad style. But this is your decision. What counts most is that code is easy to read.

A similar programming style can be achieved with exceptions. Then you don't need the local functions. But bear in mind that most developers recommend you to use Exceptions only for errors. Pressing "N" when you are asked for a confirmation is not an error.

After a few more modifications I come to the following simple code.

```
import time
import os

def open_file(file):
  os.system(file)
 
def delete_file(filefordelete):
  if not(os.path.exists(filefordelete)):
     return print("File does not exist!")
  suretodelete = input("Are you sure? Y/N ")
  if suretodelete == "N" or suretodelete == "n":
     return print("Deleting stopped!")
  if suretodelete != "Y" and suretodelete != "y":
     return
  os.remove(filefordelete)
  print("Deleting successful")

def create_file(filename):
  filename2 = str(filename) + ".txt"
  textinput = input("Text: ")
  with open(filename2, "w") as a:
    a.write(textinput)

commands = {
  "open file"   : lambda : open_file(input("File name: ")),
  "openfile"    : lambda : open_file(input("File name: ")),
  "delete file" : lambda : delete_file(input("File name: ")),
  "deletefile"  : lambda : delete_file(input("File name: ")),
  "create file" : lambda : create_file(input("Name of the file you want to create: ")),
  "createfile"  : lambda : create_file(input("Name of the file you want to create: "))
}

com = input("Command: ")
if not(com in commands.keys()):
  print("This command does not exist")
commands[com]()
```

Note that the purpose if the lambdas is to achieve that the three functions can also be used in isolation without your main program. This is always a good idea in order to make things easy to test and flexible in use. If you don't like this, you can do it without lambda.